# Javac long classpath on Windows

Tags: windows, classpath, manifest, javac

To resolve problem with long classpathes on Windows, i have create jar file with Manifest with classpath to other libs. And trying to compile like this:

```
javac -classpath classpath.jar Main.java
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone explain what i am doing wrong or why this isn't working?

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: file:/C:/projects/CPTest/CPTest.jar
```

I have compiled that class in other way and strange this.
When i run

```
java -classpath .;C:\projects\classpath-2.jar Main
```

it executes program

but when i run

```
javac -classpath C:\projects\classpath-2.jar Main.java
```

it throws compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do is made a bat file with the classpath
Like this example.bat:

> java -classpath bin\classes;bin\classes\axis.jar;bin\classes\asm-3.2.jar Main.java

Comment: no, but it will make easier to manage the long classpath.Could you please post your Manifest file?